# sectionHeaderView background image in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to get a background image in a sectionHeaderView in an ios app.  Something is not right and I need to release it as I have two values.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bar-two.jpg"];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(10,10,1,30);

    return imageView;

    APLSectionHeaderView *sectionHeaderView = [self.tblView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:SectionHeaderViewIdentifier];

    APLSectionInfo *sectionInfo = (self.sectionInfoArray)[section];
    sectionInfo.headerView = sectionHeaderView;
    sectionHeaderView.titleLabel.text = sectionInfo.climb.name;
    sectionHeaderView.section = section;
    sectionHeaderView.delegate = self;

    return  sectionHeaderView;
}
```

Comment: What's not right? And why two return, do you forget `if...else...`?

Comment: Half of the codes are unreachable due to the `return imageView` line

Comment: imageView.frame = CGRectMake(10,10,1,30);
you have kept the imageview width to be 1 pixel width is it correct??

Comment: Sorry I guess my question is how do I add a background image to teh sectionHeaderView in this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `section based header`, try like this:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if(section == 0) {
    UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bar-two.jpg"];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(10,10,1,30);

    return imageView;
    }
    else if (section ==1) {
    APLSectionHeaderView *sectionHeaderView = [self.tblView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:SectionHeaderViewIdentifier];

    APLSectionInfo *sectionInfo = (self.sectionInfoArray)[section];
    sectionInfo.headerView = sectionHeaderView;
    sectionHeaderView.titleLabel.text = sectionInfo.climb.name;
    sectionHeaderView.section = section;
    sectionHeaderView.delegate = self;

    return  sectionHeaderView; 
    }

    NSAssert (FALSE, @"Undefined header requested");

    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Thanks and I appreciate the help but now I only get a background image in one cell and the label in the other.  I need the label to show and the background also in all cells

Comment: Create a custom UIView for header, place an UIImageView in it. Set an image in it from code, and set the information on view IF NECESSARY. so it will cover both aspects.

Comment: THanks so much, that was the ticket.  I actually just placed the UIImage View inside the UIView in the xib and it placed it perfect.Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the fact that as mentioned by @shivan-raptor, it never reaches half your code (after **return imageView;** , you are creating strong references to the **sectionHeaderView** by assigning it to your ***sectionInfo.headerView*** this way, even if the header of your section gets deallocated, the sectionHeaderView still has a strong reference and never gets released (not until **sectionInfoArray** gets released). this is potentially dangerous, and you never check if your **sectionInfo** has a **headerView**! if you are going to assign it to the sectionInfo, at least check it before reassigning it!
Plus, it's better practice if you properly initialize the **sectionHeaderView** and then assign it to sectionInfo's headerView.

```
        if(!sectionInfo.headerView){

          [initialize sectionHeaderView ...]

          sectionInfo.headerView=sectionHeaderView;

        }

       return sectionInfo.headerView;
```

Comment: So my actual question is how do I add an image to a sectionHeaderView without it interfering with my above code.  I just want to add a background image but I need the other code, the return  sectionHeaderView; still to be there

Comment: @user1155141 the code I have mentioned above is for the part that you want to have a reference to your sectionHeaderView, because lets face it, you are setting its delegate, and without a strong reference, you will end up releasing it right after return ... you need to create a UIView, add any subviews like image view, labels,... to it and return that instead.